# How to order array objects by date?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date

I have an array of objects like this

```
layerArr = [
            {
               name: "layer 1"
               layerDate: "/Date(6958748400000)/"
               layerDateFormatted: "31 December 2018"
               etc...
            }
            {
               name: "layer 2"
               layerDate: "/Date(9375937500000)/"
               layerDateFormatted: "23 December 2017"
               etc...
            }
            {
               name: "layer 3"
               layerDate: "/Date(1554764400000)/"
               layerDateFormatted: "15 January 2018"
               etc...
            }]
```

How can I sort layerArr by date with the latest date first?
In this example, when layer 2 is sorted correctly, I also want the latest date to become layer 1 and the oldest date should become the last layer. (the example above is made up values)

Thanks

EDIT: the links suggested to other threads do not explain how to change "name" so that the latest date becomes `name ="layer 1"` all the way to the oldest date becoming the last layer.

Comment: Sort by `layerDateFormatted`;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects-by-property)

Comment: @MariosNikolaou I seriously doubt this is what OP wants

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

Answer (score 4):

Use `Array.sort()`:

```js
layerArr = [
  { name: "layer 1", layerDate: "/Date(6958748400000)/", layerDateFormatted: "31 December 2018" },
  { name: "layer 2", layerDate: "/Date(9375937500000)/", layerDateFormatted: "23 December 2017" },
  { name: "layer 3", layerDate: "/Date(1554764400000)/", layerDateFormatted: "15 January 2018" }
];
            
sortedLayerArr = layerArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a.layerDateFormatted)- new Date(b.layerDateFormatted);
}).map((layer, index) => ({
  ...layer,
  name: `layer ${index + 1}`,
}));

console.log(layerArr);
console.log(sortedLayerArr);
```

Comment: Thanks, this sorts by date, but it does not change the "name" property accordingly so that the latest date becomes "layer 1" all the way to the oldest date which should become the last layer.

Comment: @NickyLarson this was not mentioned before in the question

Comment: It was, the only edit I have made is the part with EDIT

Comment: @NickyLarson that is not a big problem you can just loop over the sorted array and update the name in loop